# Count based off of 2 columns in one table with a range (begin and end) from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, subquery

I am fairly new to SQL and us SQL Server Management Studio.  I have the following example tables.

Table 1:

```
[ID_ML] [MANFP]         [Begin]                    [End]             [PartN]
   1      600    2020-09-28 06:30:00.000   2020-09-28 07:30:00.000    C1939
   2      600    2020-09-28 07:30:00.000   2020-09-28 08:00:00.000    C1939
   3      600    2020-09-28 08:00:00.000   2020-09-28 10:00:00.000    C1939
   4      600    2020-09-28 10:00:00.000   2020-09-28 14:30:00.000    C1939
```

Table 2:

```
[Record] [MANFP]       [TimeStamp]  
   1       500    2020-09-28 06:40:00.000
   2       600    2020-09-28 06:41:00.000
   3       600    2020-09-28 07:25:00.000
   4       600    2020-09-28 08:32:00.000
   5       600    2020-09-28 08:34:00.000
   6       600    2020-09-28 08:38:00.000
```

I need to create a view joining the two tables
to generate a sum of table 2 "record" where table 2.Timestamp is in the range of Table 1.Begin and Table 1.End. (Note: #ofRecords ignores Record 1 because the MANFP is different, MANFP needs to match from table 1.)

Example of joined table

```
[ID_ML] [MANFP]         [Begin]                    [End]             [PartN]     [#OfRecords]
   1      600    2020-09-28 06:30:00.000   2020-09-28 07:30:00.000    C1939          2
   2      600    2020-09-28 07:30:00.000   2020-09-28 08:00:00.000    C1939          0
   3      600    2020-09-28 08:00:00.000   2020-09-28 10:00:00.000    C1939          3
   4      600    2020-09-28 10:00:00.000   2020-09-28 14:30:00.000    C1939          0
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a subquery, or lateral join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
outer apply (
    select count(*) cnt
    from table2 t2
    where t2.manfp = t1.manfp and t2.timestamp >= t1.begin and t2.timestamp < t2.end
) t2
```

Comment: This never returned a result, the database i am using is so large is the reason i assume.